# mysql Truncate table vs delete

Tags: sql, mysql, truncate

We are about to deploy some code that truncates tables in our mysql 4 database.  We are doing this to get around some replication 'weirdness' that we are seeing (and is widely known) with temp tables.  My knee-jerk reaction when I saw this in a code review was "no", but I'm having trouble backing it up.

So, the question is: am I just overreacting?  Have you run into any gotchas using truncate table in mysql that we should try to avoid?  How about truncate in a replicated environment?

Comment: What is the wierdness you find - any issues with truncate might well be overridden by this wierdness.

Answer (score 3):

Truncation (at least in Sybase, not 100% sure about mySql)

- Does NOT write to the log. Meaning, no recovery and no rollbacks.
- Does not automatically rebuild the index statistics, meaning that the optimizer may not work correctly when looking at a given table.

Please see [this article](http://mysqlmusings.blogspot.com/2006/05/replication-of-delete-from-versus.html) for mySQL specific details/comparison

Here's the [relevant mySQL TFM](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/replication-features-truncate.html)